# What does ".." do in an Meteor Spacebars statement?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I have a handlebar statement which passes a userid to a helper. I am unsure how this works. The handlebar `{{#if isowner ..}}` has .. what is passed here as parameter to the helper funktion?

```
<template name="test">
  ...
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
      {{#each tester}}
      <tr><
        <td>{{#if isowner ..}} 
                  <i class="fa fa-trash removeUser"></i>
            {{/if}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </table>
  ...    
</template>


Template.test.helpers({
  'isowner':function(parent){
    return parent.userId === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

Obviously this is only true when the userid's are identical. Meteor.userId() is the current user on the client side. So which userid is passed to `parent`?
Sure, the name speaks for its self. It must be one level above - but what is this technically? Where does .. go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..` returns the data context of the parent (enclosing) template or structure -- I rigged up a very simple MeteorPad [here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/LHLvfnJC4QWMfofH8/test) that you can maybe play around with to see how it works.

In your case, I think it's probably returning the data context for the `test` template.  You can `console.log(parent)` in your helper to inspect that object and get a bit more info:

```
Template.test.helpers({
  'isowner':function(parent){
    console.log(parent);
    return parent.userId === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

You can find more information about how the `..` is resolved and how it can be used in the [spacebars readme.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#identifiers-and-paths)

Comment: Thanks for the MeteorPad! Got it!